# How to change the font size in Raspbian LXDE

Tags: raspbian, linux, lxde

How to change the font size in Raspbian LXDE?

I've already tried the right-click on the desktop menu approach. That changes some fonts, most in fact.

But the Konsole menu fonts are still big. Given that Konsole came from KDE, so it might not respect LXDE configuration?

Any idea?

Comment: I believe console has it's own settings in the menu.

Comment: That settings do not apply for the window in which Konsole is shown.